# Simple Python Import

Tags: python, import

I have a simple Python import question. I have a module *(let's call it **A**)* that is importing a module **B**. Module B imports a lot of other modules C, D, E, F, etc. I want module A to be able to use the modules C, D, E, F, etc. Is there an easy way to do this? I don't want to directly import C, D, E, F, etc from A.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to provide an API to script developers, who write module A. So, I wanted module A only to have to include module B which is the main entry point to the API and imports all the modules in the API.

Comment: An easy way? Maybe. A good way, absolutely not. Implicitly creating C, D, E, F names in A by importing B is a Bad Idea.

Comment: After importing `B` in `A`, you can access the modules imported in `B` using the usual dot notation: `B.C`, `B.D`, etc.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: you don't want to `from B import *` !

Comment: explicit is better than implicit. your developers will thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do...

```
from B import *
```

...inside module A (although you need to make sure that there's nothing else inside module B that has the same name with anything inside module A, otherwise you'll have a namespace collision).

Once you do that, you could do...

```
C.blah()
D.testing.meh()
```

...inside module A, as usual.

Alternatively, a better solution would be to do something like the below in module A:

```
import B

B.C.blah()
B.D.testing.meh()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from ... import *` in B. After this, all definitions from C, D will be available in B namespace. But this solution is not always convenient for a large amount of code, it leads to confusion.

a.py:

```
import b
b.foo()
```

b.py:

```
from c import *
from d import *
```

c.py:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from ... import *` in both A and B files.
After this all definition either in B or C or D can be used without confusion.

A.py :

```
from B import *
fun_c()
```

B.py :

```
from C import *
```

C.py:

```
def fun_c():
    pass
```